# Show that $g(x)=f^\alpha(x)$ is also continuous uniformly in $[0,\,\infty)$.

Tags: analysis

> Suppose $f:\;[0,\,\infty)\to[0,\,\infty)$ is uniformly continuous and $\alpha\in(0,\,1]$. Show that $g(x)=f^\alpha(x)$ is also continuous uniformly in $[0,\,\infty)$.

I can only prove the case $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ by using the inequality
$$
\Big|f^\frac{1}{2}(x_1)-f^\frac{1}{2}(x_2)\Big|^2\leq\Big|f^\frac{1}{2}(x_1)-f^\frac{1}{2}(x_2)\Big|\cdot \Big|f^\frac{1}{2}(x_1)+f^\frac{1}{2}(x_2)\Big|=\Big|f(x_1)-f(x_2)\Big|.
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to note is that $x\mapsto x^{\alpha}$ is subadditive and increasing, i.e., $0\leq (x+y)^{\alpha}-x^{\alpha}\leq y^{\alpha}.$ To see this, for given $x>0$, define $h_x(y)=(y+x)^{\alpha}-(y^{\alpha}+x^{\alpha})$ and note that $h_x$ is differentiable, with $h_x(0)=0$ and $h_x'(y)=\alpha (y+x)^{\alpha-1}-\alpha y^{\alpha-1}\leq0$ for $y\geq 0,$ since $\alpha\leq 0.$ Thus, $h_x$ is decreasing, and hence, always negative. This proves the sub-additivity claim, since it's trivial at $x=0$.

Hence, for given $\varepsilon>0,$ apply uniform continuity of $f$ to get $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon^{1/\alpha}$ and note that for such $x,y$ by the above, we have
$$
|g(x)-g(y)|=|f^{\alpha}(x)-f^{\alpha}(y)|\leq |f(x)-f(y)|^{\alpha}< \varepsilon,
$$
which proves the desired.